# Source for Learning?

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I am an very ameteur mathematician and physicst (If I can say mathematician and physicst to myself xD). I want to learn topics in physics. Like electromagnetism, mechanic, thermodinamics etc. But I don't want to drown in lots of maths (Lots of fantastic variables, constants that I haven't seen in my life). I just want to understand ideas, basic of equations like that.

Can you advice a book, method, website etc. that I can do what I had written above.

Comment: Basic Laws of electromagnetism: IE Irodov Mechanics : IE Irodov

Comment: Man, isn't it important that how to learn physics? Of course it is about Physics.